# viewDidAppear Method Called before locationManager can Locate User

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I am calling a `locationManager` in my application `delegate`, and am referring back to the getUserLatitude and getUserLongitude functions in the `viewDidAppear` method of various `viewControllers`.

My issue is that my `viewDidAppear` method launches too quickly for the `appDelegate` to locate the user, and I get 0.000000 for the `latitude` and 0.000000 for the `longitude`. Does anyone know how I might fix this? Thank you!

**My appDelegate is structured with these location methods:**

```
- (NSString *)getUserCoordinates
{
    NSString *userCoordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    return userCoordinates;
}

- (NSString *)getUserLatitude
{
    NSString *userLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    return userLatitude;
}

- (NSString *)getUserLongitude
{
    NSString *userLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
    locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return userLongitude;
}
```

**I am using this bit of code to get the updated location from the appDelegate:**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    NSString *userLatitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
    getUserLatitude];

    NSString *userLongitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
    getUserLongitude];
}
```

Comment: set CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate in your .h file of delegate & do as per I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After the location manager updates the location  a delegate gets called which can be used here. You will get the control in didUpdateToLocation method after the location is updated

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Success ");
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed %d",[error code]);

}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding those bits of code above the viewDidAppear method in the viewControllers that refer back to the appDelegate. They never seem to get called though. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: did you write locationManager.delegate = self where you declared location manager

Comment: I don't believe so. I'll check it out

Comment: Probably several issues going on with your implementation. It can take several seconds to get a good fix on your location depending on your accuracy setting and filter. You will definitely need to set your view up as a location manager delegate so you get notified when your location is updated. (see the methods in this answer) From there, you can update the rest of your view. Just make sure you don't block your view/UI waiting for location to update.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue in my one app. First allocate the `CLLocationManager`, set the `delegate` to it, then call `startUpdatingLocation` method which may solves your problem.

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

After setting delegate, it calls to its delegate methods & gives us the `lattitude` & `longitude` of current location as.

```
//delegate method
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{    
    self.currentLat=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    self.currentLong=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"appDelegate newLocation %f  %f",self.currentLat,self.currentLong);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Girish! Ill check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by doing something like this.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
 {


     NSLog(@"Ahsan");
     if (!oldLocation ||
        (oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude && 
         oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude &&
         newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0)) 
     {
        //Your code comes here...
     }
 }
```